# Añadir tercera dimensión a matriz 2D

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Necesito sumar lo siguiente:
`fs = fs + A`

Sin embargo, `fs` es un array de dimensiones (739, 432, 3) y `A` es un array de dimensiones (739, 432), siendo `A` el resultado de concatenar 3 matrices R,G,B de las mismas dimensiones. Es decir:

```
A = np.concatenate((r,g,b), axis=0)
```

¿Alguien podría decirme cómo puedo introducir esa tercera dimensión en `A` o en las matrices r, g y b para poder sumarla a `fs`?

Comment: Lo siento pero no entendí :(

Answer (score 4):

Ya he dado con la solución, lo que quería era añadir una tercera dimensión en mis matrices R, G, B, las cuales tenían solo tamaño (M,N) y quería que fueran (M,N,3). En imágenes, el tercer parámetro de las dimensiones indica los canales de color, siendo 3 equivalente a RGB y 1 o ninguno a una imagen en escala de grises.

Para poder sumar a fs (que era de dimensiones (M,N,3)) mis matrices r g y b, debía añadirles el tercer parámetro de la dimensión (3), para que pudiera realizarse dicha suma. He podido hacerlo con:

```
fs = fs + np.stack((r,g,b), axis=2)
```

M y N son los mismos valores tanto para r g y b como para fs.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más fácil de añadir dimensiones con `Numpy` es usando `expand_dims`. Esta función toma dos argumentos:

1. El primero el array que quieres añadir una dimensión
2. La posición del array (axis) donde quieres añadir dicha dimensión.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

fs = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 2))
print(fs.shape)

fs = np.expand_dims(fs, axis=2)
print(fs.shape)
```

**Salida:**

```
(2, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
```

Puedes ver más sobre esta función en la [documentación oficial de Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)